# NSPredicate and CoreData - decide if a Date attribute is "today" (or between last night 12am to tonight 12am) on iOS

Tags: core-data, nsdate, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and a `UITableViewController` to populate a UITableView from a CoreData database.

I have a `NSDate` object saved into this Date attribute labeled "startTime".  Then I'm trying to only pull todays's data by using a `NSPredicate` that looks like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate == %@",
                          todaysDate];
```

I'm getting zero results.  I understand this because a `NSDate` object just hold the number of seconds or milliseconds or whatever since Jan 1 1970 right? So comparing 1111111111111 and 1111111111112, while on the same day, are two distinct `NSDate` objects that aren't equal.

So, how could the `NSPredicate` be formatted so that it would do it? I'm going to guess its creating two `NSDate` objects: one that is at 12am last night, and another for 12am tonight and compare startDate and see if its between these two `NSDate`s.

I'm kind of new to `NSPredicate`, so how could this be accomplished?

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer instead of putting it inside the question.

Comment: Can't @yuji because I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Maybe you could put **your** solution in an answer. In the meantime I have edited it out seeing as you've already accepted yuji's answer. You can recover your solution by viewing the revision history. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `NSCompoundPredicate`.

```
NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", firstDate];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate < %@", secondDate];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstPredicate, secondPredicate, nil]];
```

Where `firstDate` is 12am this morning and `secondDate` is 12am tonight.

P.S. Here's how to get 12am this morning:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendar]; // gets default calendar
NSCalendarComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, and day for today's date
NSDate *firstDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components]; // makes a new NSDate keeping only the year, month, and day
```

To get 12am tonight, change `components.day`.

Comment: Thanks very much - couple of small typos - andPredicateWithSubpredicates (lower case P) and use NSDateComponents instead of NSCalendarComponents